# CUDA 5.0 driver slow

Tags: cuda

I have just been migrating from CUDA 4 to 5 and installed the just released CUDA 5.0 on Ubuntu 12.04, but performance has gone down drastically. A particular CUDA kernel that used to take 1 second now is taking 6 seconds. It seems that the new driver is the culprit since when I re-installed the old 4 driver performance is regained, but I don't know why. Has anybody experienced similar problems?

Comment: Are the compiler statistics for this kernel noticeably different between CUDA 4.0 and CUDA 5.0 (number of registers, spill locations, etc)? Add -Xptxas -v to your nvcc command line to see the statistics. How are you measuring the kernel execution time? A simple way to measure it is to export CUDA_PROFILE=1 to turn on simple profiling, then inspect the resulting log file. This will also show the occupancy of the kernel. Are you seeing differences in occupancy betwen the two CUDA versions? What GPU are you on?

Comment: In general, this question needs way more information to be answerable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies for taking so long to get back..

I found out that the main culprit was __threadfence(). Not well understanding its use I was writing something like

```
 __threadfence()
 __syncthreads()
```

On the new drivers this was taking a lot of extra time

I am working on GTX680

Thanks a lot
Daniel